# Remove conflicts in columns in list of lists

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to make some easy way to remove any conflicts in columns of my data strucutre.

I have list of int lists, example!

```
0 0 0 2 3 4

1 0 2 3 0 0

0 2 1 4 0 0
```

As you see only 5 numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and I'd like to have **same** number or **zero(s)** in **each** column. How it should be look like for example above:

```
0 0 0 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 0 2 0 0 0 2 3 0 0 0 0

0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 4 0 0
```

So I've made a simple program in **C#** for this:

```
for (int t1 = 0; t1 < myList.Count; t1++)
      {
        for (int t2 = 0; t2 < myList[t1].Count; t2++)
            {
               for (int t3 = 0; t3 < myList.Count; t3++) 
                    {
                        if (myList[t1][t2] != myList[t3][t2])
                              {
                                 if (myList[t1][t2] != 0)
                                     {
                                        if (myList[t3][t2] != 0)
                                           { 
                                             myList[t3].Insert(t2, 0);
                                            for (int uui = 0; uui < myList.Count; uui++)
                                                {
                                                    if (uui != t3)
                                                    {
                                                        myList[uui].Add(0);
                                                    }
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }  
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

As you see I'm searching by columns and it adds zeros to every sublist except sublist with insert to avoid out of range exception.
The interesting fact is that it **usually** works! But for some instances there are still conflicts.
My question is why it works ony for some instances, (usually small ones max 5x5)?

Another example for this dataset:

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 3 4 3 3 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 4 3 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 3 2 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 3 0 0 0 3 4 3 0 0 0 0 
0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 4 1 
0 0 3 0 3 0 1 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The result is:

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 3 4 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 4 3 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 3 2 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 3 0 0 0 3 4 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 4 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 3 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Unfortunately conflicts still present: 1st List first '3' from right has number 1 below in 4th list. And '4' from 1st list has '3' below in list nr 4.

Comment: Do you also need this to "reduce" cases where all original lists have 0's at the same column?

Comment: You mean columns only with zeros? Yes I have to remove them but in next step, fisrt of all conflicts. There can be columns only with the same number and zeros, it can be even only on '1' and many of zeros above and below it

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to do?? How do you consider some row is conflict? What is your final goal, regardless of the algorithm to achieve it?

Comment: Two rows are in conflict if they have a column i where rowA[i] > 0 && rowB[i] > 0 && rowA[i] != rowB[i]. So columns like `0 0 1` or `2 0 2` are allowed, but this would be in conflict: `1 0 2`. I think this is what he meant by conflict.

Comment: @Kilanny looking for same numbers or zeros in each column just like it's shown above.

Comment: example columns: `0 1 0`, `1 1 1`, `2 0 1` are ok, but `0 1 2`,  `3 1 2`, `0 4 1` - conflicts need to be removed

Comment: @Adamm: How can `2 0 1` be ok, if you say this: "and I'd like to have same number or zero(s) in each column"? You really should try to ask more precisely.. For example in the question you say this: "1st List first '3' from right has number 1 below in 4th list.", but you mean the 5th list, not the 4th.

Comment: of course `2 0 1` is wrong, my fault! I'm working on it since morning, my brain want to go out ;p

Comment: yes 5th list not the 4th, apologizes

Comment: I don't get it, you want same number of zeroes in each column but it's ok to keep two same numbers in column which results in different number of zeroes per column. It's contradictory.

Comment: @Adamm So, what are you trying to achieve exactly? I think you didn't explain anything at all..

Comment: Yes I did.   Instance list of lists with conflicts in columns, conflict is when two different numbers are in one column zeros don't matter, they can be everywhere. Trying to to remove any conflict in each column like it is in example

Comment: So I want to insert 0 where conflict occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you encounter a conflict, you're adding at the end of the row.
Try to solve the conflict for the whole column. 
Thus lower rows can't add conflicts, which aren't resolved in later iterations.

A complete test program:

```
void Main()
{
//  var s = "0 0 0 2 3 4\r\n1 0 2 3 0 0\r\n0 2 1 4 0 0";
    var s = @"
    0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 3 4 3 3 
    1 0 0 0 0 0 1 4 3 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 3 2 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 3 0 0 0 3 4 3 0 0 0 0 
    0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 4 1 
    0 0 3 0 3 0 1 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 4 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
";

    var myList = s.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select (x => x.Split(new char [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select (y => Int32.Parse(y)).ToList()).ToList();

    Print(myList, "Before");

    int rows = myList.Count;    

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < myList[row].Count; col++)
    for (int t3 = 0; t3 < rows; t3++)
    if (myList[row][col] != 0 && myList[t3][col] != 0 && myList[row][col] != myList[t3][col])
    {           
        //Print(myList, "Before Step");
        for (int uui = 0; uui < rows; uui++)
        {
            if (uui < t3) // yours: if (uui != t3)
            {
                // yours: myList[uui].Add(0);
                myList[uui].Insert(col + 1, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                myList[uui].Insert(col, 0);
            }
        }
//      Print(myList, "After Step");
        break;      
    }       

    Print(myList, "After");
}

public void Print(List<List<int>> list, string header)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(header);
    Console.WriteLine(ToString(list));
}

public string ToString(List<List<int>> list)
{
    return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.Select (l => String.Join(" ", l)));
}
```

Comment: Amazing, I'll put your idea into my code and my other function, responsible for conflict detection returns 0 conflicts in any type of instance. Now I see my mistake. Thank You so much Frederick!

Answer (score 1):

> looking for same numbers or zeros in each column just like it's shown
>   above.

A very simple algorithm:

```
public int countNonZero(int[][] myList, int row)
{
   var res = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; ++i)
     if (myList[row][i] != 0) ++res;
   return res;
}

public void removeConflicts(int[][] myList)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i)
   {
      var iNum = countNonZero(myList, i);
      for (int j = i + 1; j < numRows; ++j)
      {
         var jNum = countNonZero(myList, j);
         if (iNum == jNum)
         {
             // row #i conflicts with row #j
         }
      }
   }
}
```